# How to use the fetch api method on Open Weather API

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the fetch method to display the current weather on a website. However, I keep getting an error stating that res is not defined. What do I need to do?

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data').then(res => {
     return res.json();
}).then(function(myJson) {
     console.log(res.coord);
});
```

Note: The API call has been edited to ensure privacy

Comment: res is NOT defined in the second `.then` ... the argument is called `myJson` there

Comment: Just goes to show I can't copy pasta my way to web development success XD thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using different parameter names in your functions. In your first function, you're using `res`:

```
.then(res => {
```

But in your second, you're using `myJSON`:

```
.then(function(myJson) {
```

Changing your code to this would fix your problem:

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data').then(res => {
     return res.json();
}).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.coord);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning how to use fetch since it's the newer way to use AJAX so I'm just working out the kinks.

Comment: No worries! If you like AJAX you may want to look into jQuery's `$.get()`, it's good